# How do I access public properties when sharing webforms codebehind for user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make an ascx control that can be templated by our front-end developers by just making a new .ascx and pointing to that specific .ascx in that instance.  However, I am having issues with accessing properties in shared code-behind scenarios.

I have the following code behind that's shared

```
public partial class TemplateCodeBehind : TemplateControlBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // Ascx Available properties
    public string GetOption1Value { get { return Option1; } }
    public string GetOption2Value { get { return Option2; } }
    public string GetOption3Value { get { return Option3; } }
    public string GetOption4Value { get { return Option4; } }
}
```

Note that those options that are returned are public properties of the `TemplateControlBase` class.  In my Templates subfolder I have the following ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="../TemplateCodeBehind.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.JqueryTemplates.TemplateCodeBehind" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace.JqueryTemplates" %>

<div>
     Option1: <%= GetOption1 %>

</div>
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to load my test ascx I get the following error

> An error has occurred. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: c:\Projects\DNN-Dev\Website\DesktopModules\Module.JqueryTemplates\Templates\Test.ascx(5): error CS0103: The name 'GetOption1' does not exist in the current context

I have tried changing `<%=` to `<%#` and calling `Page.Databind()` but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I might be missing something, but shouldn't `GetOption1` be `GetOption1Value`?

Comment: Sigh, no you aren't missing anything.  That was the issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ascx file change `GetOption1` to `GetOption1Value`